# The main method of poisson for Random number generation

Tags: java, poisson

please I saw a method that implements the Poisson distribution function to generate random numbers and I have no idea how to run it. Can someone please help me with the main method that can print the random numbers? Below are the codes:

```
 public static int getPoisson(double lambda) {

 double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
 double p = 1.0;
 int k = 0;

 do {

   k++;
   p *= Math.random();
 }

while (p > L);

 return k - 1;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: " I have no idea how to run it." Run it like every other Java function. Maybe read some Java tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public class Test {
  public static int getPoisson(double lambda) { ... your code

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Got: " + getPoisson(0.1));
  }
}
```

But the real answer is: when you want to learn programming; you do that by **studying** and learning.

Thus the **real** answer here --- turn [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and start reading and trying. Yourself.